# Format data (client-side) for (server-side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Using the following script:

```
$("#some_button").click(function() {

    var changed = [];

    $( 'input[id$="_0"]' ).each(function() {

        var new_id = this.id.replace( '_0', '_1' );

        if ( $(this).val() !== $( 'input#' + new_id ).val() ) {

            changed.push(new_id);
            // send back id, new value from _0, and old value from _1

        }

    });

    console.log(changed);

});
```

I need to send back the `id`, the old value from `_1` and the new value from `_0` back to the server.  What is the best way to format this data so I can easily extract the data from the server side so I can easily email someone for example to let them know which textboxes have changed, what the old values were, and what the new values are

At the serverside level, I am using .NET-3.5 (VB).

I know how to send the data bacl. and how to email the data, I just wanted to know how to best format the data at clientside before sending it back.

---

I could have upto 50 sets of id, old, and new values to send back.  Sorry for not making that clear earlier.

---

**Example:**

How can I modify the script above to generate this?

```
[
    {
        "id": "name_0",
        "new": "text",
        "old": "text"
    },
    {
        "id": "age_0",
        "new": "text",
        "old": "text"
    },
    {
        "id": "dept_0",
        "new": "text",
        "old": "text"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please see the example above.  Can I use jquery.serialize / jquery.serializeArray to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side:

```
changed.push(new_id)
```

instead

```
changed.push({id:new_id, new_val:$(new_id).val(), old_val:$(this).val()});
```

Later:

```
$.post(TARGET_URL, changed);
```

On the server side:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
// ...
public class Change {
    public string id {get; set; }
    public string new_val {get; set; }
    public string old_val {get; set; }
}
List<Change> changes = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(data_string);
```

Old answer, obsolte because of many items transported.

If your data is short enough, just encode it in the url.

```
var url = TARGET_URL + "?old_id="+escape(old_id)+"&new_id="+escape(new_id);
```

Comment: I could have upto 50 sets of id, old, and new values to send back.  Sorry for not making that clear earlier.

Comment: Please see new example in question above.

Comment: the answer now can be used with your example and will create the desired format. (Although you can't see it.) I read, you are using VB, but it will be easy to translate, I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = '{"0":[{"old_id":" + $(this).val() + '"},{"old_id":"' + new_id + '"}]}';
```

Send via ajax POST, and parse with the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) or [FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)

Result will look like this:

```
{
    "0": [
        {
            "old_id": "foo"
        },
        {
            "old_id": "bar"
        }
    ],
    "1": [
        {
            "old_id": "foo2"
        },
        {
            "old_id": "bar2"
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "old_id": "foo3"
        },
        {
            "old_id": "bar3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I could have upto 50 sets of id, old, and new values to send back.  Sorry for not making that clear earlier.

Comment: Please see new example in question above.

Comment: Updated - just use a JSON array :)

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](http://json.org/) is a very nice, lean data exchange format.

Something like this, might work:

```
var changed = [];

$( 'input[id$="_0"]' ).each(function() {
    var thisItemChanges = { id: this.id, newid = this.id.replace('_0', '_1') };
    changed.push(thisItemChanges);
});

$.post('UrlToPostTo', changed,  function(serverResponse) { // do something with return from server });
```

See also, [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more info on sending data to servers with javascript.

Comment: I could have upto 50 sets of id, old, and new values to send back.  Sorry for not making that clear earlier.

Comment: Please see new example in question above.